# Allow only admin users to access admin commands in discord bot

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm making a bot for the discord server and I came up with the following code solution. The problem with this code is that *anyone can use any command*. I need to restrict the admin commands to users with the Admin role. I tried this but couldn't figure out what might be the right approach.

```
#Import
import discord
import os
from discord.ext import commands

#Client
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='?')
client.remove_command('help')

#Activity
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Emog9 is running')
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.playing, name="?help"))
#Error
@client.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandNotFound):
        await ctx.reply('Command does not exist. Please use a valid command')

#Cogs
@client.command()
async def load(ctx, extension):
    client.load_extension(f'cogs.{extension}')

@client.command()
async def unload(ctx, extension):
    client.unload_extension(f'cogs.{extension}')

for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
    if filename.endswith('.py'):
        client.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')
```

`Mute.py`:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class mute(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.command()
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
        if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRole("Administrator")):
            return
            
    async def mute(self, ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
        guild = ctx.guild
        mutedRole = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='Muted')

        if not mutedRole:
            mutedRole = await guild.create_role(name='Muted')

            for channel in guild.channels:
                await channel.set_permissions(mutedRole, speak=False, send_messages=False, read_message_history=True, read_messages=True)
        await member.add_roles(mutedRole, reason=reason)
        await ctx.send(f'Muted {member.mention} for reason: {reason}')
        await member.send(f"You were muted in the server {guild.name} for reason: {reason}")

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(mute(client))
```

Answer (score 6):

Add the following decorator after the @client.command():

```
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
```

You also can specify certain roles to use the command, add the following after the @client.command()

```
@commands.has_any_role('role_name', 'role_name')
```

Note that you can use the role id as an integer instead of the role name.

Comment: @SidhakSingh You should look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers